# 'The mental and automatic processing of small sets of data'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd always thought the word was *subitemize*, but I'm apparently mistaken – a dictionary search for the word yields nothing.

The basic idea is the ability to sort/correlate/grok a sufficiently small system.

For example, I can pair six socks *very* quickly, but this is not a linear progression to, say, *sixty* socks.  It's said that I can *subitemize* those six socks (or whatever the word actually is).

Comment: You may need to clarify.  I'm not sure if you're talking *sort* or *categorize* or *classify* or what.

Comment: In practice, it was more-or-less 'all of the above', but counting was definitely the biggest element of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you want is [*subitize*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subitize) which Dictionary.com defines as

> verb
>   1. (psychol) to perceive the number of (a group of items) at a glance and without counting: the maximum number of items that can be
>   subitized is about five